# Is there a way to patch to an entity using wildcards or list of servicepaths

Tags: http, fiware, fiware-orion

Im trying to update an entity using the PATCH `/v2/entities/id/attrs` endpoint. The service of the id is known; however, the servicepath is not.

My first attempt was to leave the header empty or rather not send it at all. For a GET query, this does the job right, however for a PATCH, this returns me a 200. First question, is this the expected behavior?

Second try was to use a wildcard. I know that my entity is at SP `/automatization/<something>`. I tried PATCHing to `/automatization/#` and got a 204, but the entity did not change.

My last try was to use a list of known SPs: I know the entity I want is in one of a number of SPs, so a used a comma separated list as the SP header. Same as above: 204 but no change.

Am I missing something?

Orion version:

```
{
"orion": {
"version": "2.3.0-next",
"uptime": "2 d, 1 h, 50 m, 52 s",
"git_hash": "c99fef1b5c93bf1673d407968c2c101f01b95980",
"compile_time": "Tue Mar 10 09:46:52 UTC 2020",
"compiled_by": "root",
"compiled_in": "0a42bdf43030",
"release_date": "Tue Mar 10 09:46:52 UTC 2020",
"doc": "https://fiware-orion.rtfd.io/"
}
}
```

Comment: I opened an [issue](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/issues/3640) in github

Answer (score 2):

It's unfortunate that the service path isn't returned in the payload data of the queries. That would have solved your problem. If I were you (and if you have access to the DB) I'd use the mongo shell to find the service path of your entity.
About getting a 204, that seems like a bug. The entity you want to patch isn't found (as you put in the wrong service path) and a 404 should be returned.
Lists and wildcards as service paths are only for queries, never for creation/updates. The broker should complain there too, with a 400 and 'Invalid Service-path', if you ask me ...
Seems like we have two issues here, apart from the one to include service path in the response ...

Comment: The thing is I kind of know the SP, but I'm developing an application which consumes orions data and the application is the one that doesn't know the SP

Comment: Thanks for the answer about wildcards only being for queries. I've never used them and I thought it could solve my problem. Apparently, I would have to change the logic of the application. The 204 is still a possible issue

Comment: FYI, when you do a GET operation without specifying a Service-Path, the broker uses the default Service-Path '/#' which means: Everything matches. This is all documented, I'd advise you to read about it (that and more :))   A quick search got me this: https://fiware-orion.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/service_path/index.html

Comment: Thanks. I did know about that fact. Maybe I got deviated from my original problem, which was whether I could PATCH an entity -programmatically- without knowing the exact SP.